# show data in another dropdown, related first dropdown data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have two divs. One is input type text **(Searching for city)** and another is select option **(Select area based on city search. )**. If I type city name in first div then related city show in dropdown and when I select any city then related area in second div should be show.

My fronend is:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group mb-15">
            <input type="text" name="selectcity" id="selectcity" class="selectcity tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type your Query">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group mb-15" >
              <select required id="selectarea" class="form-control" name="selectarea"> 
              <option value="">Select Area</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Now script is:

```
<script src="typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input.selectcity').typeahead({
    name: 'selectcity',
    remote: 'search.php?key=%QUERY',
    limit: 10
}).on('typeahead:selected', function(e){
    var selectedcity = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process-request.php",
        data: "selectcity=" + selectedcity,
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#selectarea").html(data);
    });
});
});
```

search.php is:

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$key=$_GET['key'];
$array = array();

$query=mysql_query("select * from location_master where status1='1' AND location LIKE '%{$key}%'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $array[] = $row['location'];
}
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

process-request.php is

```
<?php
include("connection.php");

if(isset($_POST["selectcity"])){

    $selectcity = $_POST["selectcity"];

    $query1=mysql_query("select * from location_master where parent_id='$selectcity'") or die (mysql_error());


    if($selectcity !== 'Select City'){
echo"<option value=''>Select Area</option>";
        while($value = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
            ?>
               <option value="<?php echo $value['id'];?>" ><?php echo $value['location'];?></option>
            <?php
        }

   } 
}
?>
```

But in search.php **$array[] = $row['location'];** display accurate city. But it gives null **id** for area.

If I **$array[] = $row['id'];** then I type city in text box, then **ID** is showing in dropdown and gives accurate area in area option.

But I need display city in dropdown but **ID** should be pass of related city for area option.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thankyou for reply. I need to type city name in text box and related city should be show in text box and if I select any city then related area of that city should be show in second select option. In my code, city is showing in text box search. But I need to pass id of that city. Because related area can be show by city ID.

Comment: If I got you, you want to send the id of city to `process-request.php` through `selectedcity` variable  instead of the city name ?

Comment: yes..Exactly it is I need.